# All permutations of string using formatting

Tags: python, formatting, permutation

I have a string template and I want to generate filenames from it. It uses percent formatting with named placeholders right now, and there can be any number of parts to be replaced.

```
template = "image_%(uval)02d_%(vval)02d.%(frame)04d.tif"
```

I have an object containing the keys for placeholders, and lists of values:

```
params = {
    "uval": [1,2],
    "vval": [1,2],
    "frame": [10,11]
}
```

And I want to generate permutations with formatting:

```
[
    "image_01_01.0010.tif",
    "image_01_01.0011.tif",
    "image_01_02.0010.tif",
    "image_01_02.0011.tif",
    "image_02_01.0010.tif",
    "image_02_01.0011.tif",
    "image_02_02.0010.tif",
    "image_02_02.0011.tif"
]
```

So I tried this:

```
def permutations(template, params):
    # loop through params, each time replacing expanded with the 
    # new list of resolved filenames. 
    expanded = [template]
    for param in params:
        newlist = []
        for filename in expanded:
            for number in params[param]:
                newlist.append(filename % {param: number})
        expanded = newlist
    return expanded


print permutations(template, params)
```

And the problem is:

```
newlist.append(filename % {param: number})
KeyError: 'uval'
```

As it replaces one key at a time, only one placeholder exists in each iteration, so those that are not present cause the error. Ideally while replacing one key it should leave the rest of the template untouched.

It works fine if there's only one placeholder of course:

```
template = "image.%(frame)04d.tif"
params = {"frame": [10, 11]}
print permutations(template, params)
Result: ['image.0010.tif', 'image.0011.tif']
```

I don't mind using a different system, but ideally I want the template string to be expressive and easy to reason about.

Ideas welcome

Comment: I think its possible by replacing all the other % signs (except the current placeholder) with %%. Then by the next loop they will be back to single %. rinse and repeat. I guess a regex is in order.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.product` to select the parameters, and for each combination, build a single dictionary to use in a formatting step that replaces all the placeholders at once:

```
import itertools

def permutations(template, params):
    for vals in itertools.product(*params.values()):
        substituion_dict = dict(zip(params, vals))
        yield template % substituion_dict
```

This is a generator function, so it returns an iterator rather than a list of results. In order to print it, you'll need to pass the iterator to `list` first. But if your real code is going to do something else (like looping over the results in a `for` loop, doing something with each one), you may not need to create the list at all. You can just loop on the iterator from the generator function directly.